# how to prevent elements from breaking into different lines in a table cell

Tags: html, resize

I have a structure like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name""/>
         <input type="button" value ="save"/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My question is, I want to always keep these 2 inputs on the same line no matter how the window resizes. AND these 2 inputs takes up all the spaces of the table cell. the button is fixed size, while the text input can gets longer if the table cell grows. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
div { white-space: nowrap; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/juXWD/)

Comment: thank!! it helps. But for the second part of the question, how do i keep the other input grow/shrink as the windows size varies.

Comment: I gave it a percentage based width, so it has to grow/shrink already - just try to resize the window